# In Oracle, how do I declare a unique constraint over a pair of values AND it's reverse pair

Tags: database, oracle, constraints

I have a table that defines the rule between two variants:

```
CREATE TABLE VARIANTCOMBINATIONRULE
(
  VARRECID0  NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
  VARRECID1  NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
  RULE       NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE VARIANTCOMBINATIONRULE ADD (
  CONSTRAINT VARIANTCOMBINATIONRULE_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (VARRECID0, VARRECID1));
```

How do I create a constraint that disallows "reversed pairs"? With this I mean that if there's a record for variants 12 and 14, a new record for the reversed pair (14 and 12) shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: I don't think that you can directly... there are several options like using a trigger to ensure that sort of thing (for example by automatically inserting the reversed pair with some special marker)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_cd0_cd1
      ON VARIANTCOMBINATIONRULE (least(VARRECID0, VARRECID1), greatest(VARRECID0, VARRECID1));
```